# Turbo-charge Ansible playbooks

Tags: performance, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using Ansible to run puppet and other scripts on large number of VM (5000).
I tried using these options :

- Strategy : free
- async: 1000 
  poll: 0
- serial : 20 or 50 or 100
- forks : 20

I tried many combinations, but playbooks keep failing for some VMs , only correct option is when I used forks : 10 and serial : 2
Any idea why ? I need to reduce the time execution. 
Thanks

Comment: I am using   gather_facts: no and ansible 2.7.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/xxxxx.io/xxxxxx/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Answer (score 1):

Mitogen could help: https://mitogen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible.html

> Expect a 1.25x - 7x speedup and a CPU usage reduction of at least 2x, depending on network conditions, modules executed, and time already spent by targets on useful work. Mitogen cannot improve a module once it is executing, it can only ensure the module executes as quickly as possible.
>
> One connection is used per target, in addition to one sudo invocation per user account. This is much better than SSH multiplexing combined with pipelining, as significant state can be maintained in RAM between steps, and system logs aren’t spammed with repeat authentication events.
>
> A single network roundtrip is used to execute a step whose code already exists in RAM on the target. Eliminating multiplexed SSH channel creation saves 4 ms runtime per 1 ms of network latency for every playbook step.
>
> Processes are aggressively reused, avoiding the cost of invoking Python and recompiling imports, saving 300-800 ms for every playbook step.
>
> Code is ephemerally cached in RAM, reducing bandwidth usage by an order of magnitude compared to SSH pipelining, with around 5x fewer frames traversing the network in a typical run.
>
> Fewer writes to the target filesystem occur. In typical configurations, Ansible repeatedly rewrites and extracts ZIP files to multiple temporary directories on the target. Security issues relating to temporary files in cross-account scenarios are entirely avoided.
>
> The effect is most potent on playbooks that execute many short-lived actions, where Ansible’s overhead dominates the cost of the operation, for example when executing large with_items loops to run simple commands or write files.